# To extract all the files to a folder before starting installation

Tags: windows-installer

1. We are creating a setup. In that we want to extract all files to a folder and then we want to install it one after the other. Is there any way to carry this out?
2. During Installation we want to list the steps to be executed, to the end users, like listed during SQL installation. And highlight the process presently carried out. At present we are using Windows installer's Form design which skips from one form to other for each step carried without displaying the steps going to carry.

Thanks,
Parameswari

Answer (score 0):

The file extraction and installation is handled automatically by Windows Installer for MSI packages. You don't need to do anything special.

Regarding the installation steps, this is usually done through a custom UI. It's not supported by Visual Studio, but other setup authoring tools offer multiple UI themes that may suit your needs.